# passwordHash field in admin.auth.UserRecord interface of Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get the hashed passwords of my users using Firebase Admin SDK.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#passwordhash),

> Optional **passwordHash**
>
> ---
>
> passwordHash: *string*
>
> ---
>
> The user’s hashed password (base64-encoded), only if Firebase Auth hashing algorithm (SCRYPT) is used. If a different hashing algorithm had been used when uploading this user, as is typical when migrating from another Auth system, this will be an empty string. If no password is set, this is null. This is only available when the user is obtained from listUsers().

But after retrieving a `UserRecord` object, the `passwordHash` property is always set to `'UkVEQUNURUQ='`, irrespective of that user's password.

Users are created in the backend using the admin SDK like so

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: uid,
  email: email,
  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
  password: password
})
```

Why are the hashes all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known [bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/501).